# How to successfully install CiviCRM w/Wordpress on WPEngine hosting

Tags: wordpress, installation, civicrm.settings.php, failure

I've seen other questions indicating CiviCRM will not install properly on WPEngine, at least not without some extra work, such as: [Install problem civicrm with wordpress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9478/install-problem-civicrm-with-wordpress)

The installer says it was successful, but no menu appears and no links work.

I haven't been able to find out what exactly needs to be done to make it work, in case anyone knows.  It appears perhaps WPEngine changes where files are placed or permissions or something like that. They are very restrictive and will often delete plugins without asking us. (I do actually have a lot of years experience with web applications including Wordpress & Drupal, but in this case my hands are tied due to IT)

I just would like to know so that I can relay this info to my IT department which controls all access and communication with WPEngine (and picked them for all Wordpress hosting).
Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest answer I have is :

The issue is the way WP Engine builds the user directory structure.   We have a proposed patch in : https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8494

Until that is merged, you can use the answer listed here: [Word Press Install Missing civicrm.settings.php; dashboard unavailable; no menus](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/word-press-install-missing-civicrm-settings-php-dashboard-unavailable-no-menus/9791#9791)

Make sure the `global $civicrm_setting;` precedes `$civicrm_setting['URL Preferences']['userFrameworkResourceURL'] = 'http://example.com/example-resource-url/';`